# Foreach loop over dictionary causing StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, stack-overflow

My error is

> StackOverflowException Board.GetSquare(UnityEngine.Vector2 currentPos) (at Assets/Scripts/Board/Board.cs:111)

The stack trace is

```
Board.GetSquare(UnityEngine.Vector2 currentPos) ( at 
Assets/Scripts/Board/board.cs:111)
Board.GetSquare (UnityEngine.Vector2 currentPos) (at 
Assets/Scripts/Board/Board.cs:111)
Rook.GetMoves (System.Boolean filter) (at 
Assets/Scripts/Piece/Pieces/Rook.cs:26)
King.IsChecked () (at Assets/Scripts/Piece/Pieces/King.cs:152)
King.GetMoves (System.Boolean filter) (at 
Assets/Scripts/Piece/Pieces/King.cs:77)
King.IsChecked () (at Assets/Scripts/Piece/Pieces/King.cs:152)
...
```

`Square` is a class I've created and `boardNotation` is the dictionary. This issue seems to arise frequently from this same line of code after some big code changes of other scripts, this also causes it to go away on its own when big code changes occur. What is causing this issue?

Here are the methods involved.

```
public class Board : MonoBehaviour
{
public Square GetSquare(Vector2 currentPos)
{
    foreach(Square square in boardNotation.Values)
    {
        Vector2 squarePos = new Vector2(square.transform.position.x, square.transform.position.y);

        if(currentPos == squarePos)
        {
            return square;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
}


public Class King : Piece
{
    public override List<Square> GetMoves(bool filter)
{
    List<Square> _moves = new List<Square>();

    int range = 1;
    bool isCheck = IsChecked();

    foreach (Vector2Int dir in dirs)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= range; i++)
        {
            Vector2 pos = Vect3PosToVect2Pos(transform.position) + dir * i;
            Square newSquare = board.GetSquare(pos);

            if (newSquare)
            {
                if (newSquare.pieceOn != null)
                {
                    if (newSquare.pieceOn.team == team)
                        break;
                    _moves.Add(newSquare);
                    break;
                }
               _moves.Add(newSquare);
            }
        }
    }

    if (filter)
        _moves = FilterMoves(_moves);

    return _moves;
}

public bool IsChecked()
{
    Piece[] pieces = gm.GetPieces().ToArray();

    for(int i = 0; i < pieces.Length; i++)
    {
        if (pieces[i].team == team)
            continue;

        List<Square> _moves = pieces[i].GetMoves(false);

        if (_moves.Contains(board.GetSquare(transform.position)))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
}

public class Rook: Piece
{
public override List<Square> GetMoves(bool filter)
{
    List<Square> _moves = new List<Square>();

    int range = board.GetBoardWH();

    foreach(Vector2Int dir in dirs)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i <= range; i++)
        {
            Vector2 pos = Vect3PosToVect2Pos(transform.position) + (dir * i);
            Square newSquare = board.GetSquare(pos);

            if (newSquare)
            {
                if (newSquare.pieceOn != null)
                {
                    if (newSquare.pieceOn.team == team)
                        break;
                    _moves.Add(newSquare);
                    break;
                }
                _moves.Add(newSquare);
            }
        }
    }

    if (filter)
        _moves = FilterMoves(_moves);

    return _moves;
}
}
```

Comment: "Stack overflow" would generally imply "infinite recursion" ... and I'm not seeing any recursion at all.  Please update your post with 1) the exact error message, and 2) the relevant portion of the stack trace.  You should be able to copy/paste both from the exception.

Comment: The only way this code could cause a `StackOverflowException` is if you had already almost completely exhausted the available space in the call stack.

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer this question, can you create a minimal and reproducible example? see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for more information.

Comment: One typical SO that's hard to spot, particularly in the sparse code you have posted, is the result of poorly implemented properties.  Consider: `private string _s = "init"; public string S { get { return S; } }`.  Note that the getter is implemented in terms of the property, not the backing field.  When you access `S`, the getter accesses `S` and eventually, kaboom, stack overflow.  You can do the same with a setter.  Take a look at `boardNotation.Values` and each bit of `square.transform.position.x` (and `.y`)

Comment: _Now that you have posted some code_... That's a more interesting stack overflow than the typical one posted here.  Put a breakpoint at each entry in the stack (`Board.GetSquare`, `Rook.GetMoves`, `King.IsChecked`, etc.).  Now run your program and keep track of which breakpoints you hit (in which order).  You should see a pattern: A calls B, B calls C, C calls D, D calls A -> kaboom.

Comment: It follows a pattern of `King.IsChecked()` then `King.GetMoves(bool)` until the end but I still don't know what to do.

Comment: @Flydog57 could you expand on your explanation and maybe link some sources to help me understand. I am a pretty new developer.

Comment: Look at your code.  `GetMoves` calls `IsChecked` early on.  Then, within `IsChecked`, you call `pieces[i].GetMoves(false);`.  Think about it.  If A calls B and B calls A, unless you are very, very careful about how to end the recursion, you'll end up doing that forever.  Every call allocates some stack.  Eventually you run out.  Fixing it will require you re-thinking how you do this.

Comment: @Flydog57 You're right, thank you so much for your help. I am new to asking questions on Stack Overflow how can I give you credit for finding the issue?

Comment: I don't see any `Dictionary` in your code btw ...

Answer (score -2):

not sure, maybe you're trying to loop inside a propiety (?)

[Check Dictionary iteration on MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0)

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in myDictionary )
{
 Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

Actually it would be something like: **(where var is the type of key)**

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<var,Square> square in boardNotation)
{
 Vector2 squarePos = new Vector2(square.Value.transform.position.x, square.Value.transform.position.y);

 if(currentPos == squarePos)
    {
        return square;
    }
}
```

*I think, not sure due lack of code.*

Comment: Why would looping inside a property be an issue?

Comment: If you can explain how code in you answer can produce stack overflow that would be reasonable suggestion... So far the code shown in the answer has no reasonable way to produce that exception...

Comment: @Llama assuming that the property is an IEnumerator and is good implemented, none. (Sorry i'm new, i posted like answer instead of question xD).

MS says what is the best standar foreach a Dictionary, that's because you can iterate a List as Value, so you can make a confusion, also is not recommended use var.

I'm not sure if is a good use of a Dictionary, wich is optimized for a Key instead looping Values aka TryGetValue(). (correct me if i'm wrong)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, sorry is not intended to be an anwser!
I can't i'm not an expert, MS says: "A Dictionary<TKey,TValue> can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified. Even so, enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure."
I'll not sure what kind of exception will throw... Recommendation is Lock or Monitor...

Comment: In OP's code there is no `Dictionary` at all actually .. also: Why is using `var` bad? And why is iterating over the dictionary itself or e.g. the values bad?